# How can I set-alias for bunch of commands inside Foreach-Object?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set-alias for all the existing `powershell` commands to exclude `hyphen` from the name. eg. `Get-Alias` would be aliased to `GetAlias`. I tired to achieve it by code below, however that doesn't seem to work. The function execution completes without any error, but when I check for new aliases using `alias` cmd, nothing has been created. When I just try the `Set-Alias` outside of the loop, that works but not inside. Any idea what could I be doing incorrectly in the code below? I also tried with `Foreach-Object{//my code here}`, that didn't work either.

I am using `powershell ver 5.1`

```
function _removeHyphenFromCommmands {
        $commands = Get-Command;
        foreach ($cmd in $commands) {
            $hyphenIndex = $cmd.Name.IndexOf("-");
            if ($hyphenIndex -gt -1) {
                $aliasName = $cmd.Name.Remove($hyphenIndex, 1);
                Set-Alias -Name $aliasName -Value $cmd -Description "hyphenless";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work`? Any error? Is it because of alias capacity? Something like: `Set-Alias : Alias SetExecutionPolicy cannot be created because alias capacity
4096 has been exceeded for this scope.`

Comment: i suspect that your `-Value $cmd` is the problem. that parameter is supposed to be a STRING, but you are sending a complex object.

Comment: @robdy - I updated the question to elaborate on what 'not working' means in my case. No, I donot get any errors. @Lee_Dailey - I tried `$cmd.Name` as well, that didn't help either.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler - have you tried running the code as a script - NOT in a function? you may be seeing a scope problem. ///// also, you are running this on commands that DO NOT have hyphens in the name AND you are likely running it on the same command name more than once since you likely have older versions of various modules being read by the `Get-Command` call. i have eight copies of `Update-Module` when i run just `Get-Command` ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Thank-you for the feedback. I had just started with this script so I definitely could add checks to make it repeatable. The `if` block I had there I thought would prevent me from applying this to commands without hyphen. Is there a reason you think that might not work?

Comment: @anish - i misread your test. [*blush*] i thot you were testing for `1` instead of `-1`. i would use `$_.Name -match '-'` for the test & `$._Name.Replace('.', '')` for the removal. my understanding is that the `.IndexOf()` method is seriously slow with "large-ish" numbers of items & so is the `.Remove()` method.

Comment: Thank-you @Lee_Dailey. I appreciate the feedback. I didn't know about those perf tips.

Comment: @anish - you are quite welcome! glad to help a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `set-alias`, you are doing so within a scope. Since you are using it inside a function, theses aliases are valid only inside the function (where you instantly drop out of). You've got to set the scope via `-scope` parameter.

Comment: Your answer will have even more value if you add an example.